# How to run optimization to achieve an equal active weight portfolio?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, finance-mathematics, python, mathematics

I am trying to build an equal active weight portfolio, while minimizing the total risk. However, my constraint of equal active weight always leads to 0 active weight for everything. I know 0 active weight for everything is not the optimal result, as there's no way my benchmark happens to be the minimal risk portfolio. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
fun = lambda x: x.dot(covariance_matrix).dot(x.transpose())
cons = np.array([])  

for i in range(0,x0.size-1):        

    con = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x, i=i: (x[i]-bmWeight[i])-(x[i+1]-bmWeight[i+1])}
    cons = np.append(cons,con)       

sumCon = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  sum(x)-1}       
cons = np.append(cons, sumCon)

solution = minimize(fun,x0,method='SLSQP',constraints = cons)
```

Comment: Your constraints simply $x_i - b_i = \frac{1}{n} \left( 1 - \sum_j b_j  \right) $ for all $i$. This is zero if your $b$ weights sum to 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the ratio between explanations and code is too low

Answer (score 1):

#### Your constraints imply all the active weights must be zero!

We know that the base weights add to 1, that is:

$$ \sum_i b_i = 1$$

Define the active weight $a_i$ as:

$$ a_i = x_i - b_i$$

Hence if you have the constraint $\sum_i x_i = 1$, then the sum of the active weights must be zero. Observe that summing both sides:

$$ \underbrace{\sum_i a_i}_{=0} = \underbrace{\sum_i x_i}_{=1} - \underbrace{\sum_i b_i}_{=1}$$.

Then if you add constraints such that $a_i = a_j$ for any $i$ and $j$ then $a_i = 0 $ for all $i$ (otherwise, they wouldn't sum to zero).